# Resetting jQueryUI step after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I inherited a project that uses the JQ UI slider. Before it was fine having the step set to 200 but now it needs to change to 500 and then possible 1000 as the value of the tool tip increases.

Looking in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-step) I found that you can set the step after initialization but I think that's operating under the assumption that you didn't set it on initialization.

Does anyone have any experience setting it dynamically? I ran some searches here and didn't find anything that I thought answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set update the option dynamically by using the option setter, even if the step option has been set previously:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "step", 500 );
```

Check out [this example](http://jsbin.com/mikoyoquye/edit?html,js,output) which updates the option when a button is clicked.

Comment: As insane as this sounds, I tried that and it didn't work. Sometimes you just need someone else's eyes to make something work. Thanks!